# Computed Column Specification for full address

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a table with multiple address columns

```
Address1 | Address2 | Address3 | Address4 | City | County | PostCode
```

`Address1` and `PostCode` will always be populated, the other columns may contain null. I want to have a computed column that can hold the full address, excluding null columns, but inserting `char(10)` and `char(13)` linefeeds after each column that is not null.

Coalesce and `ISNULL` don't allow me to add the linefeeds only after non null columns, and CASE WHEN ELSE END returns null if any one column contains null.

Can this be done?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I’m using Ms sql server express

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for this. The nulls are ignored, and each one is separated by the separator value (the first parameter).

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD FullAddress AS (
  CONCAT_WS('
', Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, City, County, PostCode
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but would this also include the linefeed charscters?

Comment: Yes of course. Did you try it? If you specifically want to make sure it includes those two characters and not your default newline on your system then use `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` explicitly.

Comment: I will when back at desk, many thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    case when isnull(Address1,'')='' then '' else Address1+char(10) end
    + case when isnull(Address2,'')='' then '' else Address2+char(10) end 
    + case when isnull(Address3,'')='' then '' else Address3+char(10) end    
    + case when isnull(Address4,'')='' then '' else Address4+char(10) end     
    + case when isnull(City,'')='' then '' else City+char(10) end     
    + case when isnull(County,'')='' then '' else County+char(10) end     
    + case when isnull(PostCode,'')='' then '' else PostCode+char(10) end    full_name
from `table_name`
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the [CONCAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp) function along with [COALESCE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) function to concatenate non-null values and `CHAR()` to insert linefeeds.

```
SELECT Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,City,County,PostCode,CONCAT(
    COALESCE(Address1 + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''),
    COALESCE(Address2 + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''),
    COALESCE(Address3 + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''),
    COALESCE(Address4 + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''),
    COALESCE(City + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''),
    COALESCE(County + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''),
PostCode) AS FullAddress
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a select statement, I want to accomplish this using a formula in a computed column.

Comment: @RegJ you can use this approach in a computed column.

Comment: Crikey, my sql server knowledge is far worse than I thought  Many thanks Dale